# Is there a support community around Stanford's "CS 193P iPhone Application Development" anywhere on the web?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, cs193p

Searching Google brought me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155220/are-the-solutions-to-stanfords-online-iphone-development-course-anywhere-on-the

Searching "193p" on Stackoverflow.com did spit out a bunch of results, but they're all outdated and from 2010 or even 2009.

I'm working through the class materials and they are absolutely excellent. I've been trying to teach myself iOS programming for about two years now and have tried a bunch of different books... and got nowhere. Since I started this course, watching the lectures, doing the assignments, I've written a ton of code and am feeling a real sense of progress and excitement as I march forward. This beats any book I've ever tried, simply because it's an actual university course.

I got through Assignment 1 without much trouble and am happy with my solutions. Since I'm not a Stanford student, however, I have no way of knowing how good or even how correct my solutions really are. Assignment 2 is quite a step up in difficulty, which is welcome as I like a challenge, but I'm already a bit lost on where to even begin.

Is there a website anywhere that is dedicated to non-Stanford students working on this course? A forum perhaps, a collection of working solutions, a platform to discuss the assignments and give and get help?

As I said... googling only gave me old stuff that pertains to versions of the course from past years.